# The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data.

Tags: string, wcf, max

I am getting the error below

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to
>   deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:commentText. The
>   InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type System.String. The maximum string content length quota
>   (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be
>   increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.'.
>   Please see InnerException for more details.'. See server logs for more
>   details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> ```
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader
> ```
>
> reader, PartInfo part) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo part) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, PartInfo returnInfo,
>   Object& returnValue) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyCore(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription
>   messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

And thease are my web.config

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Frontiers.WCF.Services.MyHomeServiceBehavior" name="Frontiers.WCF.Services.MyHomeService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Frontiers.WCF.Services.IMyHomeService" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Frontiers.WCF.Services.NetworkServiceBehavior" name="Frontiers.WCF.Services.NetworkService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" contract="Frontiers.WCF.Services.INetworkService" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Frontiers.WCF.Services.WidgetServiceBehaviour" name="Frontiers.WCF.Services.WidgetService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" contract="Frontiers.WCF.Services.IWidgetService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Frontiers.SharePoint.Site.Navigation.NavigationServiceBehaviour" name="Frontiers.SharePoint.Site.Navigation.NavigationService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" contract="Frontiers.SharePoint.Site.Navigation.INavigationService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Frontiers.WCF.Services.UserProfileServiceBehavior" name="Frontiers.WCF.Services.UserProfileService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" contract="Frontiers.WCF.Services.IUserProfileService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ContactsImporterSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="819200" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="JournalActivityReportSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="eUtilsServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="eUtilsServiceSoap1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="eUtilsServiceSoap2" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="eUtilsServiceSoap3" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Have you used the same readerQuotas settings on the client as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase your maxStringContentLength="8192", the error says that it tries to read a string taller as 8192 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `maxStringContentLength="8192"` in the service **host**'s app.config.